# Mapping enum('YES', 'NO') column in Mysql to Boolean in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have mapped a Table in Mysql to Java class using hibernate. 
One of the column in the table has type "enum('YES', 'NO')". I want to map this to a Boolean in the java class using hibernate annotation.

As per the documentation below
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/types.html#types-value-basic
('Y', 'N'), ('0', '1') and ('T', 'F') can be mapped to Boolean.
How do I map "enum('YES', 'NO') to Boolean?

Comment: Why do you have an enum for boolean values?

Comment: You shouldnt have it ideally. But thats a legacy table. I can't change the schema now. I have to use it as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those types are all based on mapping a one CHAR column. I think it may be possible to map the enum to a java enum out of the box, but the only way to achieve what you want is likely to implement your own type, i.e. an implementation of [UserType](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is older post, but maybe someone helps. I needed a conversion of String to Boolean and back.

I wrote a converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class BusinessEnvironmentConverter implements AttributeConverter<Boolean, String> {
    enum BusinessEnvironment { TEST, PRODUCTION }

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final Boolean production) {
        return production ? BusinessEnvironment.PRODUCTION.name(): BusinessEnvironment.TEST.name();
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbField) {
        final BusinessEnvironment businessEnvironment = BusinessEnvironment.valueOf(dbField);
        return businessEnvironment.equals(BusinessEnvironment.PRODUCTION) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
@Column(name=PRODUCTION, nullable=false)
@Convert(
        converter=BusinessEnvironmentConverter.class,
        disableConversion=false
)
private boolean production;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, not compiled:

```
public class SomeEntity {
    ....
    public enum YesNoEnumType {
        YES, NO
    }


    private YesNoEnumType someBooleanField;

    @Column(name = "SOME_BOOLEAN_FIELD)
    @Enumerated(YesNoEnumType.STRING)
    private YesNoEnumType getSomeBooleanField() {
        return this.someBooleanField;
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Its mapped to YesNoEnumType here. I want to map it to Boolean java type and not to an enum.